# SharePoint 2007: Programmatically Start workflow hit error

Tags: sharepoint, workflow

I wanted to programmatically start workflow when itemAdded in Pages Library.
I do as following :

```
public override void ItemAdded(SPItemEventProperties properties)
{
    SPListItem listItem = properties.ListItem;

    StartWF(listItem);
}

public void StartWF(SPListItem listItem)
{
    using(SPWeb web = listItem.Web) {
        using(SPSite site = web.Site) {
            SPWorkflowManager manager = site.WorkflowManager;
            SPList parentList = listItem.ParentList;
            SPWorkflowAssociationCollection associationCollection =
                parentList.WorkflowAssociations;

            foreach(SPWorkflowAssociation association in
                associationCollection) {
                if (association.Name == "APWFAnn2010") {
                    string data =
                        association.AssociationData;
                    SPWorkflow wf =
                        manager.StartWorkflow(listItem,
                                  association,
                                  association.
                                  AssociationData);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

then I hit this error "**The system cannot find the file specified. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070002)**"

"APWFAnn2010" is the workflow name I wanted to start. It is SP default Approval Workflow created in Pages Library.

Please help, thank you in advance.

Comment: Could you just step through your code in debug mode and tell us what line causes the error? The error message "cannot find the file" is pretty descriptive...

Comment: After debug, the error is hit on manager.StartWorkflow().
hope this help

Answer (score 0):

First of you have your `using site` within the `using web` it should be the other way around - on the other hand I don't even see you using the SPWeb, so why have it in there?. And secondly I would rewrite the code a bit:

```
public override void ItemAdded(SPItemEventProperties properties)
{
    SPListItem listItem = properties.ListItem;
    spSite = properties.OpenWeb().Site;
    spWeb = properties.Web;
    using(spSite) {
        StartWF(listItem, spSite);
    }
}

public void StartWF(SPListItem listItem, SPSite spSite)
{

    SPList parentList = listItem.ParentList;
    SPWorkflowAssociationCollection associationCollection =
        parentList.WorkflowAssociations;

    foreach(SPWorkflowAssociation association in associationCollection) {
        if (association.Name == "APWFAnn2010") {
            association.AutoStartChange = true;
            association.AutoStartCreate = false;
            association.AssociationData = string.Empty;

            spSite.WorkflowManager.StartWorkflow(listItem,
                                 association,
                                 association.AssociationData);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also pass in the name into the function above by doing it this way, and then you'd have a function that can start any workflow on any item:

```
public void StartWF(SPListItem listItem, SPSite spSite, string wfName)  
{ 
   SPList parentList = listItem.ParentList;      
   SPWorkflowAssociationCollection associationCollection = parentList.WorkflowAssociations;        
   foreach (SPWorkflowAssociation association in associationCollection) 
   {
       if (association.Name == wfName) 
       {
           association.AutoStartChange = true;
           association.AutoStartCreate = false;
           association.AssociationData = string.Empty; 
           spSite.WorkflowManager.StartWorkflow(listItem, association,  association.AssociationData);
      }
   }
}
```